# Permanent solution to "Remote server returned '550 5.7.708 Service unavailable."

Tags: node.js, email, heroku, office365

I have an application set up on **heroku** that sends emails for OTP and the likes, I know the solution to the error stated above is to delist the IP address at https://sender.office.com/, but heroku doesnt provide static IP addresses.
Is there any work around I can implement for this?
The application is built in NodeJs and it is an Outlook email address

If an email is sent by the server/application , it fails and the reponse is

```
Remote server returned '550 5.7.708 Service unavailable. Access denied, traffic not accepted from this IP. For more information please go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=526653 AS(8561) [AS8PR10MB6995.EURPRD10.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2024-03-12T14:14:02.621Z 08DC42177C557961]'
```

*Update* 
I settled on using a third-party service like SendGrid or mailersend